# How to install packages from command line on Suse

Tags: installation, command-line-interface, yum, apt, sles

What is the Suse version of `apt-get` or `yum`? Or how do I get one of them installed in order to install software packages from the command line?

A fairly intense session of googling suggests that it may be `yast` or `yast2`, but no sensible HOWTO of listing and installing packages from the command line seems to exist. (maybe I am looking in the wrong place)

If I am an administrator for a remote Suse server, how do I install packages from the command line? (Not using a GUI and preferably installing from a central repo)

Comment: `zypper install PACKAGENAME` is in default like `apt update && apt install PACKAGENAME`, `zypper update` is in default like `apt update && apt upgrade`, for more info use `zypper --help`.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider [my answer on U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/679874/318461) which partly answers your question.

First of all, answer the question. "Your" openSUSE uses **`zypper` package manager** as the default, which is not so bad. You can have a look at [the documentation](https://documentation.suse.com/smart/linux/html/concept-zypper/index.html) as [Gerald Schneider](https://serverfault.com/users/38644/gerald-schneider) commented for how to use it. You named [YaST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YaST), which can be used to *install other package managers* such as (partly taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61313166/4575793)):

- [apt4rpm](http://linux01.gwdg.de/apt4rpm/) or [zypper-aptitude](https://software.opensuse.org/package/zypper-aptitude) which let you get the feel of `apt`(-get), the package manager for Debian + Ubuntu + Linux Mint and all Linux Distributions build in Debian
- Redhat, fedora and CentOS are using [`dnf`](https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:DNF)/[`yum`](https://electrictoolbox.com/install-yum-on-opensuse-with-yast/) package manager, which are also RPM-based package managers, [`dnf`](https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:DNF) actually being a fork which just uses libsolv as dependency resolver.

---

BUT [the big problem problem will be to find repos](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/suse-opensuse-60/installing-yum-on-suse-372106/), as you probably want to use the (non-`zypper`) package manager to install software - and there will not be many repos for them. So to adress this, there comes the frustrating part of this answer. You can of course always [build the Debian packaging system (`dpkg`/`apt`) from source](http://packages.debian.org/stable/admin/apt-src).But I would be doing you a huge disservice by not telling you why you shouldn't do that, so I'll do that for you as well. SUSE is built around RPMs and while I like dpkg better than RPM, I would never try to convert an RPM based distro to a debian based distro because they're architected differently. This is partly taken [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12730004/4575793), where there also is more Info.